# C# Make external application's form type Sizable

Tags: c#

Well, I have the code to make it borderless, but I'm having troubles changing it back to sizable

This is the code to make to make it borderless:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]    
static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, IntPtr dwNewLong);


const int GWL_STYLE = (-16);
const UInt32 WS_VISIBLE = 0x10000000;
SetWindowLong(windowHandle, GWL_STYLE, (IntPtr)(WS_VISIBLE));
```

Comment: Be aware that even if you achieve this, if the application isn't sizeable already, it may not scale/reposition it's components when you resize it.

Comment: Thanks, huge help!

Comment: SetWindowLong() has a return value, don't lose it.  It is the previous value of the style, the one you want to apply again to restore the appearance.